# djangorestframework: use kwargs instead of requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My code is littered with a lot of parsing keys from `request.data` objects inside functions, which  makes it hard to follow data flow. How can I change from

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def greet(request):
    # FYI for Character.AI we use the chat and not this stateless_chat view.
    payload = request.data

    user = payload.get("user", "test")
    friend = payload.get("friend", "bart")
    num_friends = int(payload.get("num_friends", 16))
    return None
```

to

```py
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def greet(user:str='test', friend:str='bart', num_friends:int=16):
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at DRF Serializers (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). In addition to cleaning up your code they provide additional advantages like validation for example.

It's not exactly what you wanted (I don't think that's even possible) but using Serializers is following best practices working with DRF.